# Button with is not working in Mozilla Firefox and working in Google Chorme

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, button, anchor

I have a form having two buttons working correctly with Google Chrome but is not working in Mozilla Firefox. What should I have to do?

```
<td>
    <button type="button">
        <a href="edit_teacher.php?edit=<?php echo $row['teach_id']; ?>">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style="font-size: 20px; color: green;"></span>
        </a>
    </button>
</td>
<td>
    <button type="button">
        <a href="delete_teach.php?del=<?php echo $row['teach_id']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('The Record will be Deleted....???');">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="font-size: 20px; color: #ac2925;" ></span>
        </a>
     </button>
</td>
```

Comment: @utility what the "which version" has to do with anything? its simple button!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `a` tag outside the `button` tag. Otherwise the button will consume the event.

```
<td><a href="edit_teacher.php?edit=<?php echo $row['teach_id']; ?>"><button type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style="font-size: 20px; color: green;"></span></button></a></td>
<td><a href="delete_teach.php?del=<?php echo $row['teach_id']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('The Record will be Deleted....???');"><button type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="font-size: 20px; color: #ac2925;" ></span></button></a></td>
```

The [HTML5 spec for button](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) actually makes putting interactive content inside a button invalid.

> **Content model:**
>
> Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

So Firefox is rightfully disallowing interaction with content inside a button.